# How to unit test observable that returns an http.patch response?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new in unit test on angular 8.
I want to test an observable function that returns an http.patch response inside a service classe :

```
updateStatus(id: string, status: string): Observable<any> {
    if (id === undefined || id === null || status === undefined || status === null) {
        throw new Error('Cannot validate');
    }
    if (environment.role !== 'manager') {
        return this.http.patch<string>(`${environment.ApiUrl}${id}/${status}`, {});
    } else {
        return this.http.patch<string>(`${environment.ApiUrl}${id}/${status}`, this.httpOptions);
    }
}
```

and the function that calls the observable is :

```
update(pt: IPointView, status: string) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.pointsService.updateStatus(pt.id.toString(), status).subscribe(
    value => {
        this.context.info(pt.id, `Update the status to ${status}`, pt);
        this.isLoading = false;
        
        if (pt.ptType === this.ptTypeRode ) {
            this.open(pt);
    }
    },
    error => {
        this.context.error(pt.id, `Error to update the status to ${status}`, pt);
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
    );
}
```

How I can test this update methode ? I want to cover the hole code inside this function.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to mock the service so before calling the "update" you can do something like :

```
spyOn(yourService, 'updateStatus').and.returnValue(of("yourString"));
```

Than way you really control what could be returned by the server in the benefit of your test.

(This line have to be in the test itself, before the actual call to your "update" status... Never in the production code)

Comment: but I want to cover the code inside subscribe for both cases value and error

Comment: If you want to test two behaviors (when everything is ok and when there is an error) you should create two tests. In the first one (succeed) you can use the configuration line I wrote above and in the second one (error) you can use this line to simulate the error:
`spyOn(yourService, 'updateStatus').and.throwError("thisIsAnError");`